# Build a macos executable from an ios app's source code

Tags: swift, xcode

I have an iOS app with some business logic. I would like to create an executable which would expose some calculations from the cli, so that I don't have to use the app.
Unfortunately, the code with the business logic that I want to expose depends on lots of other parts of the code, eventually pulling almost all the code. Even worse, it depends on some dependencies that are not available on macos (UIKit or DJISDK via pods).

I just want to write a `main.swift`, parse the arguments and use some functions from the codebase. What is the simplest way to do that ?
I don't mind if it's ugly (like pulling whole of UIKit in the executable) as long as it doesn't take to much time to implement.

I have two ideas:

- remove all dependencies, optionally defining "dummy" classes compiled only for this target for some dependencies. That requires changing a lot of code, but seems to be cleaner.
- find a way to pull the whole app in the new target. For example I have a UnitTests target which does that and can run on mac (though an app window appears when the tests run). But I have no idea how to do that.

Any help or guidance to good documentation would be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: One solution would be to move the business logic to a Swift Package but first you need to resolve your major problem, that the business logic code depends on UIKit (and that other library perhaps). This is a problem I think you need to fix anyway even if you are not creating a new app.

Comment: I agree, unfortunately it's not something I can do in one day. I added an answer to share my methodology

Answer (score -1):

I did my best to remove all unneeded dependencies, but there was a lot left that couldn't be removed easily. I resulted in using "dummy" classes to be able to compile without providing any logic.
Though it's not super elegant, it's a nice way to cut the dependency chain, and will let me remove the dependencies over time, while still being able to compile.

Ex:

```swift
// In common source file
class Business {
  func usefulComputation() -> String {
    ...
  }

  func unneededFunction() -> UselessObject {
    ...
  }

// In my CLI-target project
// file `DummyUselessObject.swift`
class UselessObject {
  // add any function called from source file here, without putting any logic
}

// `main.swift`
let business = Business()
print(business.usefulComputation())
```